# Winform autofocus on DrawingUserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an issue using a DrawingUserControl in a Winform. What is happening is When i click onto the user control to add some drawing into it its parent form scrolls down to the bit of the page where the control is. This happens before the drawing is done, causing the thing i am trying to draw to be drawn below where i originally clicked.

Is there someway i can prevent the control from getting focus when i click into it? 
I have tried setting autoscroll to false on the parent from, but this didn't do anything.

Thanks

Comment: I can understand you want to prevent a control from being focused but I don't get what your original problem is? What is `DrawingUserControl`? a custom class of `UserControl`? What can it do?

Comment: Sorry, should of explained better. Yes drwaingUserControl in a custom class of a UserControl - which adds some logic for adding drawings and label etc to an image inside the usercontrol. What's happening is when i click into it to add some drawing it gets focus, causing the parent form to scroll and the postion of the drawing to be different from where i originally clicked

Comment: how do you add some drawing to your `DrawingUserControl`? It looks like that you just draw some thing onto an image and draw that image on your `DrawingUserControl`?